# Mind Fray Debuff Amount

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within, xcom-long-war

What are the debuff amounts caused by Mind Fray in the Long War mod? (B15d2 specifically)

On the [wiki](http://ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Psionic_%28Long_War%29) it states:

> Causes the target to lose grip on reality, inflicting penalties to
>   Aim, Will, area-of-effect attack range, and mobility, and doing one
>   base damage.

Besides mentioning the 1 base damage, there are no amounts given for the debuff to aim, will, AoE, or mobility.

Does anyone know the specifics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Causes the target to lose grip on reality, inflicting penalties to Aim [-25], Will [-25], and mobility, and doing 5 base damage. Robotic units are immune. Lasts 3 turns. 1 turn cooldown.

From the [Xcom wikia](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Mindfray).These are values from the vanilla version,but the aim and will debuff are still correct for long war(can confirm this myself).The only thing that has changed in Long War is that damage is down from 5 to 1 and the reduction of area-of-effect range,for which I don't know any values.

There is no mention of the actual mobility reduction either,but by testing myself I've found it to be a 50% slow.I could verify this by reading some posts in the [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/) some time ago.

If I were to make a new tooltip it would read:

> Causes the target to lose grip on reality, inflicting penalties to Aim [-25], Will [-25], area-of-effect attack range[whatever],  and mobility[-50%], and doing 1 base damage. Robotic units are immune. Lasts 3 turns. 1 turn cooldown.